# How can I start spyder IDE on windows?

Tags: python, spyder

I have installed spyder and pyqt5 with

```
pip install spyder
pip install pyqt5
```

Then I run in the command line

```
spyder3
```

But nothing happens
How can I start spyder on windows?

Thanks

Comment: Better install Anaconda. it comes with all required handy tools.

Comment: I need it outside anaconda

Comment: You can launch it from outside of Anaconda also. And anaconda installs lots of good libraries too, which you can use for data analysis purpose also.

Answer (score 0):

Go to this location and make a short cut:

```
C:\Python36\Lib\site-packages\spyder\app\start.py
```

Replace `Python36` with the folder in which you installed python. If you double click on `start.py` it will run spyder.

Edit: you can find the spyder .ico online and use it for the shortcut.

Comment: It gives me an error, an unhandled win32 exception occurred in python.exe

Comment: @MiguelSantos Sure you're at the right place? I've been using spyder on several computers for a while, and I just copied / paste the link i'm using on my shortcut. My spyder install was performed from the cmd with the command: `py -3.6 -m pip install spyder`

Comment: @MiguelSantos Or maybe you got an issue during the installation of spyder / python.

Comment: I just uninstalled spyder and installed using your command, when executing the start.py (double clicking) it gives me an error

Comment: @MiguelSantos Could you post the error and the version of python used, I'm really surprised.

Comment: @MiguelSantos, are you using Windows 32 bits? I say it because perhaps `pyqt5` is only available for Windows 64 bits. However, Anaconda has package for 32 and 64 bits.

Comment: I just uninstalled everything, including python and all the packages, and installed from scratch and just worked.